# Do not install dependencies on conan install

Tags: python, conan

Is there a way to **not** install dependencies of a conan package, on using the command `conan install` ?

Comment: What do you want to do? ``conan install`` is a command to install dependencies. If you don't want to install dependencies, why would you call ``conan install``? You need to elaborate a bit more about what is what you want to achieve.

Comment: @drodri I have defined conanfile.py where i have mentioned all the packages which i need. I need to install these packages without bringing in the dependencies of them.

Comment: Conan Download is the command what you are looking for: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/misc/download.html